# How to set an image size in pixels in WPF?

Tags: wpf, layout

I am using 32x32 pixels images in a toolbar in WPF. How can I set the width of the images to be exactly 32x32 pixels instead of DPI system ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure this is something you really want to do, especially with a toolbar? DPI system was developed for a reason, so your application scales well. To me first sign of an amateur app is when I open it on my media PC which is 10 ft away from me and while the rest Windows UI is looks great at 150% scale, there's that one app where GUI developer hard-coded all pixels.

Comment: I know, but the icons look blurry when they are enlarged.

Comment: ah, you are using bitmaps instead of vector-based images. Did you try Expression Design for creating icons? Take a look at this page, might find something useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315819/source-for-xaml-toolbar-icons

Comment: I am using 3rd party PNG images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [reference of the size properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx), you can qualify them.

Comment: But it looks like there is no way to specify pixels. "px" in WPF means device independent unit and not pixels.

Comment: @Naza: As DXM noted there is a reason for this and i would not recommend going against it. One workaround would be to bind the properties and put in a converter which retrieves the resolution and inverses any implicit scaling.